# How can I get the Schema for SObjectFiled?

Tags: rest

Hi I want the xsd/wsdl any form of schema related structures for each type of SObject like Lead,Opportunities,Sales etc.
How do i get it?I know that describe will  give me a list of the fields available for the Object but not in the form of an xsd/wsdl.
Also I am using REST API's to communicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a WSDL file for your org by going to Setup->Build->Develop->API and click on 'Generate Enterprise WSDL'. 
The Enterprise WSDL will contain your full schema in xsd structure.

For the REST API, you don't need to use the WSDL. You can explore the API by going to
https://{instance}.salesforce.com/services/data/v24.0

For an interactive explorer, check out apigee's salesforce console:
https://apigee.com/console/salesforce

Fetching the WSDL/XSD schema from the REST API is not possible  by my knowledge.